# Need to upload file using mat form field in angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Need to upload file using mat-form-field and save to database using web API dot net core. Currently I am using mat-form-field for save other data to database. Now I am trying to upload file (Image) using mat-form-field and need to send it to web API controller. Any method?

Answer (score 0):

```
//In the .html U.I You would accept the file like so

<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx">

//Then in the .ts backend 

fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(`${this.apiEndPoint}`, formData, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log('success'),
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

Here is an example you can place the input into your Mat Field Form,

Then once you have the file from the user you can map it to the backend and make the http call back to the API